# ActiveRecord Association / Seed Data with Multiple IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am building a schedule for sports teams and have a many to many relationship between a `Schedule` and a `Team`.

My association appears to work, as I can assign a single `schedule_id` to a `team` but I want to assign that `schedule_id` to two `Teams` or the reverse of that, so two `Teams` to one `schedule_id`

When done like this, it assigns `schedule_id: 1` to `team_id: 1`

```
# Team Seed Data
team_name: 'Team One',
schedule_id: 1
```

I thought I might be able to enter `schedule_id` as an array but that does not work. So:

```
team_name: 'Team One',
schedule_id: [1, 2]
```

But a `Team` has_many `Schedules` (so games) and a `Schedule` has_many (well two) `Teams`.

So my question is, can I assign `schedule_id: 1` to `team_id: 1` and `team_id: 2`?

Or do I need to add a migration to do it in the reverse and assign `team_id: 1` and `team_id: 2` against the `Schedule` table as `team_id_home` and `team_id_away` or something similar?

**Update with Models and Migrations as requested**

Models

```
# team.rb
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :players
  has_many :schedules
end

# team_schedule.rb
class TeamSchedule < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :schedule
end

# schedule.rb
class Schedule < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :teams
  has_many :players, through: :teams
end

# player.rb
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :schedules, through: :teams
end
```

Migrations

```
# create_teams.rb
class CreateTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :teams do |t|
      t.string :team_name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

# create_schedules.rb
class CreateSchedules < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :schedules do |t|
      t.string :leagueGame
      t.string :home
      t.string :homeAbr
      t.string :away
      t.string :awayAbr

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

# team_schedules.rb
class CreateTeamSchedules < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :team_schedules do |t|
      t.belongs_to :team, index: true
      t.belongs_to :schedule, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_column :teams, :schedule_id, :integer
  end
end

# add_column_to_players.rb
class AddColumnToPlayers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :players, :team_id, :integer
    add_column :players, :schedule_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Comment: How did you set up the many-to-many realtionship between `Schedule` and `Team`? Can you post your models and migrations?

Comment: @Gerry updated question with migrations and models.

Comment: Your many-to-many association between `Schedule` and `Team` is incorrect, you need a third table to connect them. Check [the rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many) to get more info. Once you set up your associations correctly you will be able to pair n teams with n schedules.

Comment: @Gerry have added a third model to connect as suggested but still cannot get it to work. I have updated my models and migrations in my question.

Comment: I didn't notice the columns `home` and `away` columns, so i got a question: do you want to use those columns with the association? If so, then you probably don't need a many-to-many association.

Comment: @Gerry currently the `home` and `away` columns on the `Schedule` migration just contain the names of given home / away team as a string. I'm not concerned if these are not available in the association. 
I'm new to trying to understand Associations so I probably have not followed convention and I can guarantee you I haven't done this the best way possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your associations are incomplete; both `Team` and `Schedule` should have an association with `TeamSchedule`. Your current code only adds those associations on `TeamSchedule`, so you need to update `Team` and `Schedule`, like this:

```
# team.rb
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :players
  has_many :team_schedules
  has_many :schedules, through: :team_schedules
end

# team_schedule.rb
class TeamSchedule < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :schedule
end

# schedule.rb
class Schedule < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_schedules
  has_many :teams, through: :team_schedules
  has_many :players, through: :teams
end
```

With that setup, now you can pair multiple teams in the same schedule using `team_schedules` table.

Although, it won't be easy to set up a *game* that way, so instead of associating `TeamSchedule` with **one** team at a time, lets associate it with **two** teams.

First, update your migration:

```
class CreateTeamSchedules < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :team_schedules do |t|
      t.string :home_team_id
      t.string :away_team_id
      t.string :schedule_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_column :teams, :schedule_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Next, update `team_schedule.rb`:

```
class TeamSchedule < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :home_team, class_name: "Team"
  belongs_to :away_team, class_name: "Team"
  belongs_to :schedule
end
```

With these to updates, now your `TeamSchedules` will contain two `Team` ids (home and away) in one record. This means that you can do this:

```
schedule = Schedule.create(schedule_attributes)
team1 = Team.create(team_name: "Team 1")
team2 = Team.create(team_name: "Team 2")

game = TeamSchedule.create(schedule_id: schedule.id, home_team_id: team1.id, away_team: team2.id)

game.home_team.team_name
#=> "Team 1"
```

This type of association should fit best your specific scenario where you will be able to create different *games* (i.e. `team_schedules`) combining any `Schedule` with any two `Teams`.

Comment: thanks @Gerry, `schedule.rb` is that supposed to be `has_many :schedules, ...` or should it be `has_many :teams, ...` ?

Comment: You are correct, my bad, should be `has_many :teams, through: :team_schedules`. I'll edit.

Comment: additionally, do I need the line `add_column :teams, :schedule_id, :integer` on the `create_team_schedules.rb` migration?

Comment: @RedHendery No, you don't, the only table holding foreign keys should be `team_schedules`.

Comment: Thanks @Gerry, hopefully my last question, do I seed data to the `Team_schedules` table or does `schedule_id: 1` go to `team_id: [1, 2]` against my `Team` data?

Comment: @RedHendery Check the updated answer with updated associations for your specific scenario (hint: you won't need arrays to seed).

Comment: After a few hours of fiddling with this it now goes. Thank you very much for your help @Gerry